# buffer size limit for getline in C++

Tags: c++, file, getline

I have a simple C++ program which reads a file line by line. Some lines contain more than 20000 characters. The following program can only read 4095 characters of those big line. I think it is because of the buffer size limit. What is the solution to read the big lines ?

```
// reading a text file
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    int main () {
      string line;
      ifstream myfile ("new.fasta");
      if (myfile.is_open())
      {
        while ( getline (myfile,line) )
        {
          cout << line.length() << '\n';
        }
        myfile.close();
      }

      else cout << "Unable to open file";

      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your text file has over 20K characters before it hits a newline?

Comment: @NathanOliver Yes, sometimes more than 30K also

Comment: What happens if you do `line.reserve(20000);` after you declare it?  That will help narrow down if it is `getline` or the growing of the string that is the issue.

Comment: I just tested in my system, using your program and I was able to read more than 30k char. Are you sure your data does not have a newline delimiter?

Comment: I tried with another file and it works great . It seems there is some problem with the input file.

Comment: Can you add the file to pastebin or something?

Comment: If you don't want the actual contents of the file you could alternatively use istream iterators and simply output the line length when they encountered a '\n'.

Comment: If you are using windows, you might be able to use [CreateFileMapping](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366537(v=vs.85).aspx). That way you could look for the **new line** character manually without actually loading any of it into memory. The drawback is you would be limited to windows and you cannot use the `std::string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `sed ${n}p | wc` on your input, where `n` is the line number in question.  My guess is wc will report it to be 4095 characters, or there's something special at position 4096.

`std::getline` has no buffer-size limitation, per the standard.